# django how to return a list of entries from just one field

Tags: django, object

I have a model, Designs. This contains several fields, one of which is a datetime field, date_submitted.

How can I return a list of just the datetime fields from a list of objects? For instance, I have:

```
design_list = Design.objects.all().order_by('-date_submitted')[:10]
```

But this contains all the fields. How can I isolate just the date_submitted fields into a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) for QuerySets:

Comment: Thanks very much. When I try that, I can get a list of dates, but it doesn't seem to be in datetime format, because I can't do: strftime on it. I get the following error: AttributeError: 'ValuesListQuerySet' object has no attribute 'strftime'. How can I convert from ValuesListQuerySet to the values? And I get 'tuple object has no attribute strftime' for individual items in that list.

Comment: Use `flat=True` to create a flat list instead of a nested one, then you can call `strftime` on each one.

Answer (score 0):

```
[design.date_submitted for design in Design.objects.all().order_by('-date_submitted')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use values_list.

```
design_list = Design.objects.all().order_by('-date_submitted')[:10].values_list('design_list')
```

More on [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)